# Rendering Dundas Chart Programatically throwing Exception

Tags: asp.net, charts, code-behind, dundas

I am making an application which has quite heavy (in sense of data) charts to be rendered when the ASP.NET page is loaded, due to this reason the page is taking much time to load and a white screen is shown. I am using [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com) chart API for my charts.

As a workaround I am trying to load the charts within Ajax calls. In this approach I render whole of page at once and once it is rendered, I send an Ajax call to server for chart control.

To render chart control I am using following code

```
private string GetSummaryGraph()
    {
        Chart chart_analysis = new Chart();
        chart_analysis.ID = "chart_analysis_1";
        chart_analysis.BackColor = Color.Black;
        chart_analysis.EnableViewState = true;
        chart_analysis.Height = 217;
        chart_analysis.ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseImageUrl;
        chart_analysis.ImageUrl = "~/MyApp/ChartImages/MyChart_#SEQ(1000,720)";
        chart_analysis.ImageType = ChartImageType.Png;
        chart_analysis.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Dundas;
        chart_analysis.ViewStateContent = SerializationContent.All;
        chart_analysis.Width = 996;

        // Set all styling here, like ChartAreas, Series.

        string chartImgURL = chart_analysis.GetCurrentImageUrl(); // this line throws exception "Object reference not set to instance of object"

        string html_chart = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        chart_analysis.RenderControl(htw);

        html_chart = sw.ToString();
        return html_chart;
}
```

for some reason when I call the function `chart_analysis.GetCurrentImageUrl();` it is throwing exception with following stacktrace

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Dundas.Charting.WebControl.Chart.a(String )
   at Dundas.Charting.WebControl.Chart.GetCurrentImageUrl()
   at GetSummary.GetSummaryGraph() in D:\Projects\MyApp\GetSummary.aspx.cs:line 4492
```

However if I place a chart control in `.aspx` page rather than `.aspx.cs` file, this function works fine.

**Edit**

I have also tried to render control before calling `GetCurrentImageURL()`, and I get the following exception in this case as well.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Dundas.Charting.WebControl.Chart.a(String )
   at Dundas.Charting.WebControl.Chart.GetCurrentImageUrl()
   at Dundas.Charting.WebControl.Chart.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at GetSummary.GetSummaryGraph() in D:\Projects\MyApp\GetSummary.aspx:line 4494
   at GetSummary.LoadChartData() in D:\Projects\MyApp\GetSummary.aspx:line 4378
```

It looks like I am missing some initialization which is automatically done when chart is placed in `.aspx` file. but I am unable to find what is this exactly?

Comment: What is missing is the page steps, like the preinit, init, pageload etc. Inside this steps this chart make initialization and other stuff that is needed to be run.

Comment: @Aristos, the function `GetSummaryGraph()` is being called from `Page_Load`

Comment: Same problem. Did you get to a solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because at that time you ask for it the chart control have not been run yet.

Also you run your chart control into a string and not direct on the page.

Consider two thinks.

Ether try to get the current image url **after you render the control**, ether you simple do not need it because the control automatically runs into memory and you get the html that you have to place on a point on your page.

In any case you need to run the control steps to make available the parameters of it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, actually I was thinking in same way and have tried to call `RenderControl` before getting imageurl, but RenderControl also throws exception. I have updated the question accordingly, have a look

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I used the ASP.NET charts with same technique and they work fine.